Merge two dataframes by replacing nans in r
I have the following two dataframes:
df_1
     TE    TS   LULC     DD     RI   Soil     FA
TE   NA 0.049  0.077 -0.119 -0.692 -0.035 -0.154
TS   NA    NA -0.559 -0.462  0.035  0.189 -0.196
LULC NA    NA     NA -0.210 -0.210  0.091 -0.028
DD   NA    NA     NA     NA -0.077 -0.476  0.266
RI   NA    NA     NA     NA     NA  0.497 -0.315
Soil NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA -0.476
FA   NA    NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA

and
df_2
         TE     TS   LULC     DD     RI   Soil FA
TE    1.000     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA NA
TS   -0.113  1.000     NA     NA     NA     NA NA
LULC -0.013 -0.295  1.000     NA     NA     NA NA
DD   -0.047 -0.371 -0.392  1.000     NA     NA NA
RI   -0.665 -0.034  0.082 -0.242  1.000     NA NA
Soil -0.196  0.249  0.184 -0.588  0.492  1.000 NA
FA    0.091 -0.649 -0.002  0.335 -0.438 -0.557  1

which I want to merge so that they NA values from the each dataframe are replaced by the real values of the other dataframe. In particular, I would like to construct the following dataframe:
df_3
     TE        TS       LULC     DD       RI       Soil     FA
TE   1         0.049    0.077    -0.119   -0.692 -0.035    -0.154
TS   -0.113    1        -0.559   -0.462  0.035    0.189    -0.196
LULC -0.013    -0.295   1        -0.210 -0.210    0.091    -0.028
DD   0.047     -0.371   -0.392    1      -0.077   -0.476    0.266
RI   -0.665    0.034    0.082     -0.242  1        0.497   -0.315
Soil -0.196    0.249    0.184     -0.588  0.492    1       -0.476
FA   0.091     -0.649   -0.002     0.335  -0.438   -0.557     1


Have a look on upper.tri() and lower.tri() and combination techniques. This is a dupe for sure, but I do not manage to find one.

df3 <- df1; df3[upper.tri(df3)] <- df2[upper.tri(df2]] ?

Or replace(df1, is.na(df1), df2[!is.na(df2)])

df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0; df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0; df1 + df2 is yet another approach.
